# Geometrical Interpretation of Vectors Addition

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

I was reading the Kenneth Hoffman book and came across this explanation.

I don't understand what it means by $(y_1-x_1, y_2-x_2, y_3-x_3)$.

This is the part of the book:

The directed line segment $PQ$, from the point $P = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$ to the
point $Q = (y_l, y_2, y_3)$, has the same length and direction as the directed
line segment from the origin $0 = (0, 0, 0)$ to the point $(y_l - x_1, y_2 - x_2,
y_3 - x_3)$. Furthermore, this is the only segment emanating from the origin
which has the same length and direction as $PQ$. Thus, if one agrees to
treat only vectors which emanate from the origin, there is exactly one
vector associated with each given length and direction.

Comment: For example, if $P=(1,3,6)$ and $Q=(7,8,10)$, then it’s $(6,5,4)=(7-1,8-3,10-6)$

Comment: The notation might be confusing. If a coordinates are $x,y,z$, then $(x_2-x_1, y_2-y_1, z_2-z_1)$ notation might be more helpful.

Comment: Try drawing a picture.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't draw or imagine it

Answer (score 1):

The point is that while the line segment $PQ$ is fixed in space, the vector (“directed line segment”) $\vec{PQ}$ is “portable” by translation in space. Think of a vector as describing a translation, rather than as being affixed in any particular position.

At the risk of stating the obvious: if $$\vec{PQ}=\begin{pmatrix}  -1\cr2 \cr 0\end{pmatrix}=\vec{OA},$$ then $$\vec{PQ}=\vec{OA}.$$